# Pattern for extending an ansible role variable that has a defaul value

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I wonder if there is a standard/recommended way to modify a role variable in Ansible.

As a role author you profile a set of defaults for your role and the user has the freedom to override these.

The problem appears when that defaults are lists or dictionaries which could also be big ones. You do not want to force the consumer to copy/paste them so you do want to merge them, allowing consumer to add extra values, maybe even override some keys for dictionaries.

Ansible does not merge by default, which is good. I hope that nobody is insane enough to try to alter [hash_behavior](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-hash-behaviour) value in their config.

What I seen in the wild is people adding a second variable like `myrole_filelist_extend` which is combined at runtime with the `myrole_filelist` which contains the defualt values.

There is also the other side of the coin where the user may want to remove something from the default list, while keeping the rest, and maybe avoiding to duplicate the default because he wants to benefit from changes into defaults made directly inside the role.

I kinda find that approach bit ugly as it creates more variables, sometimes extra set_fact steps for combining the two and even confusions, where some people miss to use the correct one.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the below will totally hit your target as it will still require to add some extra vars. But this will work without extra `set_fact`.

You did not give an example of the kind of list you wanted to manage. Since you mentioned `filelist` in your variable name, I suspect it is a simple list of strings. Although you could manage more complex lists of objects with the same pattern it might be a bit of a headache.

The test `playbook.yml`

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  roles:
    - role1
```

In `role1/tasks/main.yml`

```
---
- name: Show file list
  debug:
    var: role1_files
```

In `role1/vars/main.yml`. The interesting part about that file is that it is harder to override than `defaults/main.yml` below. So that somewhat protects the variables in there and users are not really supposed to mess with those. See [ansible variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) for details.

```
---
role1_files_default:
  - /home/user/file1.sh
  - /tmp/test.txt
  - /etc/toto.cfg

role1_files: "{{ (role1_files_default | difference(role1_files_blacklist)) + role1_files_add }}"
```

An finally in `role1/defaults/main.yml`. These are actually the only variables you will expose to the users who want to customize the role.

```
---
role1_files_blacklist: []
role1_files_add: []
```

You can now easily blacklist files from and add files to you protected defaults. I use `extra_vars` for convenience in the below proof tests but these declarations should go in your playbook/inventory

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml 

PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [role1 : Show file list] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "role1_files": [
        "/home/user/file1.sh",
        "/tmp/test.txt",
        "/etc/toto.cfg"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e "{'role1_files_blacklist':['/etc/toto.cfg']}" -e "{'role1_files_add':['/some/other/file','/var/lib/supp']}"

PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [role1 : Show file list] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "role1_files": [
        "/home/user/file1.sh",
        "/tmp/test.txt",
        "/some/other/file",
        "/var/lib/supp"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```